# Синдром большого города

Tags: кавычки

Ув. филологи! Следует ли заключать в кавычки?

Синдром "большого города"

или

"Синдром большого города"

(о загрязнении воздуха, хроническом стрессе и т.д.)

Answer (score 2):

Правильно: синдром "большого города", хотя написание без кавычек тоже встречается.

Синдром - это комплекс симптомов, характерных для какого-л. заболевания. Например, есть синдром хронической усталости (СХУ), здесь кавычки обычно не ставятся (хроническая усталость - это болезнь).

Но синдром "большого города" - это краткое УСЛОВНОЕ название (поэтому нужны кавычки), фактически это синдром невротического состояния, связанного с жизнью в большом городе.